# JavaScript to Create HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, grid-layout

I'm currently trying to use JavaScript to create a table using the number of elements from two other created tables. Here is what I'm trying to do so far:

HTML:

```
<!-- Scrollable y-axis line of days above the scheduler -->
  <div id="table-wrapper-days">
    <div id="table-scroll-days">
      <table id="dayRow">
        <tr>
          <td>Monday 5/7</td>
          <td>Tuesday 5/8</td>
          <td>Wednesday 5/9</td>
          <td>Thursday 5/10</td>
          <td>Friday 5/11</td>
          <td>Saturday 5/12</td>
          <td>Sunday 5/13</td>
          <td>Monday 5/14</td>
          <td>Tuesday 5/15</td>
          <td>Wednesday 5/16</td>
          <td>Thursday 5/17</td>
          <td>Friday 5/18</td>
          <td>Saturday 5/19</td>
          <td>Sunday 5/20</td>
          <td>Monday 5/21</td>
          <td>Tuesday 5/22</td>
          <td>Wednesday 5/23</td>
          <td>Thursday 5/24</td>
          <td>Friday 5/25</td>
          <td>Saturday 5/26</td>
          <td>Sunday 5/27</td>
          <td>Monday 5/28</td>
          <td>Tuesday 5/29</td>
          <td>Wednesday 5/30</td>
          <td>Thursday 5/31</td>
          <td>Friday 6/1</td>
          <td>Saturday 6/2</td>
          <td>Sunday 6/3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Scrollable x-axis column of employees to the left of the scheduler -->
  <div id="table-wrapper-employees">
    <div id="table-scroll-employees">
      <table id="employeeCol", class="tableEmployees">
        <tr><td>Employee A</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee B</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee C</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee D</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee E</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee F</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee G</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee H</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee I</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee J</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee K</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee L</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee M</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee N</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee O</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee P</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee Q</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee R</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee S</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee T</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee U</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee V</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee W</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee X</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee Y</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Employee Z</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

  <!-- Main body table to house the task graphics -->
  <div id="table-wrapper-scheduler">
    <div id="table-scroll-schedular">
      <script>createMainTable()</script>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
function createMainTable() {
  var rows = document.getElementById('dayRow').getElementsByTagName("td").length;
  var cols = document.getElementById('employeeCol').getElementsByTagName("tr").length;

  var drawTable += '<table class="tableTasks">';
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    drawTable += '<tr>';
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      drawTable += '<td>Task</td>';
    }
    drawTable += '</tr>';
  }
  drawTable += '</table>';

  document.write(drawTable);
}
```

The problem is, when I run this, nothing shows. I am trying to use the JavaScript to create a grid lined table that will later be used as a scheduler. I'm sorry that everything is hard coded in for testing purposes at this time. I'm learning HTML as I go along with this project.

Comment: If you're using google Chrome, Mozilla or IE, you can try using the devtools to debug your code and find where things are failing.

Comment: You can use the developer tools in any browser, just press F12.

Comment: `id="employeeCol",` <-- typo

Comment: `var drawTable += '<table class="tableTasks">';` <-- the error should be in your console

Answer (score 1):

One side note but it's too big for comment and it have code.

`document.write` should be avoided, when you call it, it will clear the page because it call open, to create table in JS, you can use this code, which I think is the shortest.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = drawTable;
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

the longer code would require to call `createElement` for `<tr>` and `<td>` and created tree like structure for you table like this:

```js
  var rows = 10, cols = 10;
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  table.className = 'tableTasks';
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    table.appendChild(tr);
    for(var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      td.innerHTML = 'Task';
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
  }
  document.body.appendChild(table);
```

And errors in your code:

```
function createMainTable() {
  var rows = document.getElementById('dayRow').getElementsByTagName("td").length;
  var cols = document.getElementById('employeeCol').getElementsByTagName("tr").length;

  // var drawTable += '<table class="tableTasks">';
  // it should be this, because your create variable so it don't exist before
  var drawTable = '<table class="tableTasks">';
  // for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  // in JS you need to use var not int like in java
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    drawTable += '<tr>';
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      drawTable += '<td>Task</td>';
    }
    drawTable += '</tr>';
  }
  drawTable += '</table>';
  // this will remove your other tables.
  document.write(drawTable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your method at `onLoad` attribute in ?

that should be:

```
...
<body onLoad="createMainTable()"></body>
...
```

or you try to put your code directly at `<script></script>` in `<div id="table-scroll-schedular">`

that should be:

```
<div id="table-scroll-schedular">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //paste your code at here without function declaration
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: `createMainTable()` is called inline within the table. There is no need for the `onLoad` event in this instance.

Comment: Just do the 2nd case which I told you :))

Answer (score 0):

I actually used int instead of let in my javascript for loops which caused the error.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
   drawTable += '<tr>';
   for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      drawTable += '<td>Task</td>';
   }
      drawTable += '</tr>';
}
drawTable += '</table>';
```

Replace the int with let fixed my problem. Thanks anyways!